# Call function from within another function

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to call a function from within another function, and use the returned variable.

```
function getUserEmail($clean_useremail){
    // Get the POST var
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         $useremail = test_input($_POST["useremail"]);
    }
    // Santize
    $clean_useremail = filter_var($useremail), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if isset($clean_useremail){
        return $clean_useremail;
        // here is where I want to run createXML() using $clean_useremail
    }else{
        echo 'Error, no email received from form.';
    }
}

function createXML(){
    // create xml
}
```

The first function `getUserEmail()` is called when a form is submitted via POST. It should get the data from the form, sanitize it and store it.

The function `createXML()` I want to run afterwards, and make use of the variable `$clean_useremail`

Comment: So what's your question/problem?

Comment: `if isset($clean_useremail)` should be `if(isset($clean_useremail))`

Comment: `createXML();` won't be called with `return $clean_useremail;` above it.

Comment: Call it with `$xml = $this->createXML();`

Comment: @Fred-ii- `if ($clean_useremail)` would probably suffice since `filter_var` returns `false` on failure

Comment: @andrew You've a point there.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just call `createXML` from within `getUserEmail`?

```
function getUserEmail($clean_useremail){
  // Get the POST var
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $useremail = test_input($_POST["useremail"]);
  }
  // Santize
  $clean_useremail = filter_var($useremail), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  if(isset($clean_useremail)){
      createXML($clean_useremail);
      return $clean_useremail;
      // here is where I want to run createXML() using $clean_useremail
  }else{
      echo 'Error, no email received from form.';
  }
}

function createXML(){
  // create xml
}
```

Call it before you return `$clean_useremail`

and place `isset($clean_useremail)` between ()

Comment: If this is inside a function. No code will run below the Return, if this is not in a function. Using return will throw an error

Comment: If my example is used in his code it will work, it's not meant to be used outside a function